# Swift2: CGEventSetFlags with multi CGEventFlags

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to trigger a shortcut keys such as `ctrl+cmd+space`

At first my code is like this:

```
let source = CGEventSourceCreate(.CombinedSessionState)
let keyDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, 49 as CGKeyCode, true)
let keyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, 49 as CGKeyCode, false)
CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, .MaskCommand)
CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, .MaskControl)
CGEventPost(.CGSessionEventTap, keyDown)
CGEventPost(.CGSessionEventTap, keyUp)
```

But it doesn't work because `.MaskControl` has overwriting `.MaskCommand` which means I need to use method `CGEventSetFlags` only once and set both command key and control key.

So I google it and find that you can do like this in Swift1: `CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, .MaskCommand | .MaskControl)`. Does it right? Well, I'm use Swift2 and it's not work. And I tried `CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, [.MaskCommand, .MaskControl])`, also not work.

So, please tell me the right way to use `CGEventSetFlags` in Swift2. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Or" the raw values and create a new `CGEventFlags` item

```
let commandControlMask = (CGEventFlags.maskCommand.rawValue | CGEventFlags.maskControl.rawValue)
let commandControlMaskFlags = CGEventFlags(rawValue: commandControlMask)
CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, commandControlMaskFlags)
```